# how to replace multiple whitespaces with single whitespace in Dart and Flutter

Tags: dart

I am accepting values from textfield and want to remove multiple whitespaces from those values and replace them with single one how can I achieve this in dart so far I have tried,

```
' '.join(mystring.split())
```

but this seems not to work as it does in python it throws join cannot be performed on string in dart So how can I do it in dart...

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The smallest and simplest solution would be:

```dart
final _whitespaceRE = RegExp(r"\s+");
String cleanupWhitespace(String input) =>
    input.replaceAll(_whitespaceRE, " ");
```

You can also use `split`/`join`:

```dart
String cleanupWhitespace(String input) =>
    input.split(_whitespaceRE).join(" ");
```

It's probably slightly less performant, but unless you're doing it all the time, it's not something which is going to matter.

If performance really matters, and you don't want to replace a single space with another single space, then you can change the RegExp to:

```dart
final whitespaceRE = RegExp(r"(?! )\s+| \s+");
```

Very unlikely to matter just for handling user input.

Answer (score 1):

Something like:

```
final newstring = yourstring.replaceAllMapped(RegExp(r'\b\s+\b'), (match) {
  return '"${match.group(0)}"';
});
```

or

```
final newstring = yourstring.replaceAllMapped(new RegExp(r'/\s+/'), (match) {
  return ' ';
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
def clean_words(Complex_words):
    List_words =Complex_words.split()
    New_word = ""
    for i in List_words:
        New_word = New_word + " "+ i

    return New_word
```

Comment: this is not a Dart solution. It is Python.